# ncurses good practices: clear screen with windows

Tags: linux, ncurses

ncurses app checks if terminal has been resized. If the size is less than 80x25, then blank the screen and show error message.

If the app has N windows, should all of them be removed with `delwin()`, or calling `clear()` would be enough? On the other hand, can already existing windows be later reused after `clear()` - to refresh and display contents if terminal size became satisfactory - or they should be recreated?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the windows sounds like the application's behavior rather than ncurses as such.  The ncurses library (see [`resizeterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resizeterm)) will clear areas if the windows increase in size.

The best policy when resizing really depends on what you have inside the windows.  ncurses is making reasonably safe changes, but since it has no information about your intention in making some things close on the screen, and others separated, all it can do is to attempt to resize windows so that their contents are preserved.  The application can still clear them and start over again — as well as moving windows around on the screen.

It's your decision whether it is simpler to recreate the windows or reuse them.

As long as all of the rebuilding is done before the next repainting of the screen (e.g., with [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html)), ncurses will make the updates with as little activity as it can.